# How to pause/wait for button to be not disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

With Ruby on Rails, I am running a Selenium service.  I am running through a web page many times.

Having a bit of trouble as I need it to sometimes wait for the the 'button' to be active  (in a not disabled state).

```
# wait for a specific element to show up
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "foo") }
```

So I am trying to use 
the wait.until method below but can't get the syntax.  I tried this.

````
```
  def css_removed_timeout(css)
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(timeout: 10)
    wait.until { !find_css(css).displayed? }
  end```
````

Is there anyway to detect 'not displayed'?  ( is there an 'is_empty' equivalent in Ruby)?

Answer (score 0):

There's an `.empty?` method on Arrays.

If you include ActiveSupport, there's a `.blank?` method which works on arrays, strings, and hashes.

More simply you could check `if array.length == 0`